# How can I join two tables of an Oracle database containing all rows (not the intersection)

Tags: oracle, join

I have a Oracle database with a table `t1` with:

```
cod | text1
-----------
1   | aaa
2   | bbb
3   | ccc
```

table `t2` with:

```
cod | text2
-----------
2   | abc
4   | mlc
5   | asc
```

how can I optain something like:

```
cod | text1 | text2
-------------------
1   | aaa   |
2   | bbb   | abc
3   | ccc   |
4   |       | mlc
5   |       | asc
```

If I try to do:

```
select * from t1
inner join t2 on t1.cod = t2.cod
```

doesn't works, it gives me only the intersection or something.

Comment: use `FULL JOIN`

Comment: That would be a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, not `INNER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that I should test my SQL script as well, but I don't have time to make a test before leaving for work!  I can make a SQL Fiddle later, but for now it seems that no one has quite answered the question correctly.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.cod, t2.cod) cod, t1.text1, t2.text2
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.cod = t2.cod
ORDER BY cod;
```

If you want to test the performance, use the link  to the SQL Fiddle below!

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7af155/4)**

## ***EDIT***:

So, a commentor below asked why I used `COALESCE`.  It's because of the `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  In this case, you are asking the query to return rows `WHERE t1.cod = t2.cod`, but the `FULL OUTER JOIN` ensures that `NULL` entries are returned whenever there is no match.

In these cases, you can't know if a particular `cod` will be in table `t1`, table `t2`, or in both, so by using `COALESCE` you ensure that so long as a one of the tables has the field `cod` (which is guaranteed, since you did a `FULL OUTER JOIN`), this will be filled in.

***WARNING***: One of the alternative posted responses is an incorrect solution.

Applying that erroneous query

```
select t1.cod, t1.text1, t2.text2 from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.cod=t2.cod ORDER BY cod;
```

yields `NULL`s in the `cod` fields if the `cod` was only present in table `t2`.

See this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7af155/2)** for confirmation of the error.

**However**, applying my query with `COALESCE` will yield the desired results.

Use this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7af155/4), to confirm.

Comment: I was trying something like test=# select cod from t1 union select t2.cod from t2 order by cod; How would I bring in the text with this construct?

Comment: Why `COALESCE(t1.cod, t2.cod)` ?

Comment: **Why use `COALESCE`?** Because you have to if you want to return the `cod` values for all columns.  In fact, the answer above mine, which has 2 upvotes, is actually incorrect!  I''l show as much in a edit to my post.

Answer (score 2):

select t1.cod, t1.text1, t2.text2 from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.cod=t2.cod

Answer (score 1):

Use "full outer join".
Your query should like,

select * from t1 full outer join t2  on t1.cod=t2.cod